# Laravel api.php - the GET method is not supported for route

Tags: laravel

I made a website on a local computer, after transferring it to the server and https API requests stopped working

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('/shop/search', SearchController::class);
```

call this url:

```
https://server.example/api/shop/search
```

Unit tests work for post requests , but requests from `Postman` or other utilities display an error `{ "message": "The GET method is not supported for route api/shop/search. Supported methods: POST." }`

If I change in `api.php` to `get` method - it works.

Tried various solutions that I found on this topic, but still post requests are not processed over HTTPS.

In `Postman` I don’t confuse post and get request.It would be too obvious. Moreover, I use 3-4 different HTTP clients

Added disabling `csrf token` verification in `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` for all routes `'*'`

There is no redirect on the nginx server, I checked with a request from the browser, it can also send post requests

Every time cleared the cache from console `php artisan optimize:clear`

By default add `Content-Type` and `Accept`  `application/json` request headers

`php artisan route:list` it is not resourceful route, its regular

`POST  api/shop/search ..................... Api\Shop\SearchController`

Comment: Problem 1: you are making a GET request, when you have only defined a POST route, so naturally it will fail.  Problem 2: The syntax of your POST route is incorrect - you did not [include the method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-default-route-files) in your `SearchController` which should handle the request.  The syntax you have is what you would use for a [resource route](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: My guess is your problem is a typo - `Route::post('...')` should be `Route::resource('...')`. If you have all expected methods in your controller then your GET request would work, maybe that's why you expected it to work.

Comment: Your update does not address problem 2, right?  Missing method name, incorrect syntax?

Comment: @Don'tPanic  Are you sure you read the question? I have a POST request that reports an error in using GET

Comment: And you don't think invalid syntax matters?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Please read about modern PHP and what it is `Single Action Controllers` in Laravel, you have interesting ideas, but you need to improve your base.

Comment: Thanks, I had not heard of single action controllers in Laravel, TIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in incorrect configuration of the `nginx` server. I won’t indicate where the error was in the configuration file, it doesn’t make sense, but if you take and use the `nginx` configuration file from the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment), then you won’t have such an error when you send a `POST` request, and Laravel considers it `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to get that error, when you make a call like this `https://server.example/api/shop/search` you are sending a `GET` request, and you define this route with `POST` request inside your API routes.

Define the same route again but with `GET` method, it is normal to define the same route with different methods and each method is handled by different function inside your controller.

```
Route::post('/shop/search', [SearchController::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/shop/search', [SearchController::class, 'search']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, did you use the POST method or the GET method? If you used GET, that might be the error, because the route expects a POST method. Try changing the method in Postman, as shown in the image.

[Postman screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx1Jn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this route: `Route::post('/shop/search', SearchController::class);` you are using resource routes when you are doing this call `https://server.example/api/shop/search`. You can to do in your console `php artisan route:list` and with this command you can show all your routes, and you can show your route post, normally, routes `POST` it´s for store, update, delete `in laravel`. Also, if you use routes `POST`, you shuld send `csrf_token` in request. if you are sending petitions with forms, you can add in your form `@csrf` before all inputs.

Comment: Please read manual first about  `Single Action Controllers`  this controller is not resource-based.  I agree with you, any post request is used `csrf_token` . Disabled token usage for all routes in `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` -> '*'